# Page Not Found when posting a bit longer html using Javascript Ajax to ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

I know this issue has been reported quite some number of times but I am unable to resolve my problem. I am using Javascript AJAX (no jquery) to post some data from html textarea (formatted with CKEditor) to ASP.NET aspx page.

If I post small data, I get the response from aspx page but if I increase the content to 15-20 lines, I get Network Error 404. Here is the screenshot of Firebug Console Error:

[image: Firebug Console Error]

Request Headers (From Firebug Net Panel):

[image: Request Headers]

And the output is blank so:

[image]

The behavior is same on localhost and live website.

Javascript Code:

```
//function that reads a form and create list of parameters
function submitajaxform(formid, btnid, wid, rid, url, fsuccess, ferror) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(formid).elements;
    var params = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
            //check if valid value exists
            if (elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value != '') {
                params += elem[i].id + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value) + "&";
            }
        } else if (elem[i].type == "checkbox" || elem[i].type == "radio") {
            params += elem[i].id + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].checked) + "&";
        } else if (elem[i].type == 'textarea' && elem[i].className == 'ckeditor') {
            params += elem[i].id + '=' + window.escape(CKEDITOR.instances[elem[i].id].getData()) + '&';
        }
            //element none of select, checkbox & radio
        else {
            params += elem[i].id + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].value) + "&";
        }
    }
    ajaxmethod = "POST";
    globalajax(btnid, wid, params, url, rid, fsuccess, ferror);
}

//function that creates ajax request and sends it
function globalajax(btn, wid, prm, url, rid, fsuccess, ferror) {
//if already running, reschedule to run after 1 second
    if (ajaxfinish == 1) {
        setTimeout("globalajax('" + btn + "','" + wid + "','" + prm + "','" + url + "','" + rid + "','" + fsuccess + "','" + ferror & "')", 500);
        return;
    }
    //very important to put this here:
    ajaxfinish = 0;
    //================================
    //disable button if supplied
    if (btn != '' && document.getElementById(btn) != null) {
        document.getElementById(btn).disabled = true;
    }
    //shows wait msg if container supplied
    if (wid != '' && document.getElementById(wid) != null) {
        document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' class='imginline' alt='Please Wait...' />"
    }
    //shows wait box on result container
    if (rid != '' && document.getElementById(rid) != null) {
        document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' class='imginline' alt='Please Wait...' />";
    }
    //dont run if ajax is not free
    if (ajaxrequest.readyState != 0 && ajaxrequest.readyState != 4) {
        setTimeout("globalajax('" + btn + "','" + wid + "','" + prm + "','" + url + "','" + rid + "'" + fsuccess + "','" + ferror & "')", 500);
        return;
    }
    //very important to put this here:
    ajaxfinish = 1;
    //===============================
    var curts = new Date().getTime();
    prm += "&curts=" + curts;
    ajaxwaiting = 0;
    if (ajaxmethod == "POST") {
        ajaxrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxrequest.open(ajaxmethod, url + "?" + prm, true);
    }
    ajaxrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //check if request complete
        if (ajaxrequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxrequest.status == 200) {
            var ajaxresponse = ajaxrequest.responseText;
            //enable button
            if (btn != '') { document.getElementById(btn).disabled = false; }
            //if response is to reload page (check if any message is to be displayed);
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 6) == 'RELOAD') { window.location.reload(); return; }
            //if response is to redierct page
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 8) == 'REDIRECT') { var desturl = ajaxresponse.substr(9, 100); window.location = desturl; return; }
            //end wait in wid
            if (document.getElementById(wid) != null) { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = ''; }
            //end wait in rid
            if (document.getElementById(rid) != null) { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ''; }
            //if error or message is to be displayed, it would contain 'ER;'
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 2) == "ER") {
                if (document.getElementById(wid) != null) { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = ajaxresponse.substr(3, (ajaxresponse.length - 1)); };
            }
            else {
                //write output (if not preceded by 'ER;')
                if (document.getElementById(rid) != null) { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ajaxresponse; }
            }
            //if success function is defined, run it
            if (fsuccess != '') { setTimeout(fsuccess, 100); }
            ajaxfinish = 0;
            ajaxwaiting = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (ajaxrequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxrequest.status != 200) {
            //enable button
            if (btn != '') { document.getElementById(btn).disabled = false; }
            //write error in wait
            if (wid != '') { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/error.gif' width='20' height='20' class='imginline' alt='Error' />An error has occurred. Please try again."; }
            //nullify result container
            if (rid != '') { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ""; }
            //if error function is defined, run it
            if (ferror != '') { setTimeout(ferror, 100); }
            ajaxfinish = 0;
            ajaxwaiting = 0;
            //log it
            //---
        }
    }
        ajaxrequest.send();
    setTimeout("globalajaxabort('" + btn + "','" + wid + "')", 1000);}
```

There are some global variables that are used here, I have not included their declarations.

Comment: If u sending large amount of data then you should Use `POST` instead of `GET` ..

Comment: can u add ur `ajax ` request and  also server side code that u get data ..

Comment: @AnantDabhi - included the Javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modification on your ajax request .. changed it `get` to `post` let me know its work for you or not.

```
//function that reads a form and create list of parameters
function submitajaxform(formid, btnid, wid, rid, url, fsuccess, ferror) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(formid).elements;
    var params = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {

        if (elem[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
            //check if valid value exists
            if (elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value != '') {
                params.push([elem[i].id, encodeURIComponent(elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value)]);

            }
        } else if (elem[i].type == "checkbox" || elem[i].type == "radio") {

            params.push([elem[i].id, encodeURIComponent(elem[i].checked)]);

        } else if (elem[i].type == 'textarea' && elem[i].className == 'ckeditor') {

            params.push([elem[i].id, window.escape(CKEDITOR.instances[elem[i].id].getData())]);
        }
            //element none of select, checkbox & radio
        else {
            params.push([elem[i].id, encodeURIComponent(elem[i].value)]);
        }
    }
    ajaxmethod = "POST";
    globalajax(btnid, wid, params, url, rid, fsuccess, ferror);
}

//function that creates ajax request and sends it
function globalajax(btn, wid, prm, url, rid, fsuccess, ferror) {
    //if already running, reschedule to run after 1 second
    if (ajaxfinish == 1) {
        setTimeout("globalajax('" + btn + "','" + wid + "','" + JSON.stringify(prm) + "','" + url + "','" + rid + "','" + fsuccess + "','" + ferror & "')", 500);
        return;
    }
    //very important to put this here:
    ajaxfinish = 0;
    //================================
    //disable button if supplied
    if (btn != '' && document.getElementById(btn) != null) {
        document.getElementById(btn).disabled = true;
    }
    //shows wait msg if container supplied
    if (wid != '' && document.getElementById(wid) != null) {
        document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' class='imginline' alt='Please Wait...' />"
    }
    //shows wait box on result container
    if (rid != '' && document.getElementById(rid) != null) {
        document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' class='imginline' alt='Please Wait...' />";
    }
    //dont run if ajax is not free
    if (ajaxrequest.readyState != 0 && ajaxrequest.readyState != 4) {
        setTimeout("globalajax('" + btn + "','" + wid + "','" + JSON.stringify(prm) + "','" + url + "','" + rid + "'" + fsuccess + "','" + ferror & "')", 500);
        return;
    }
    //very important to put this here:
    ajaxfinish = 1;
    //===============================
    var curts = new Date().getTime();

    prm.push(["curts", curts]);
    ajaxwaiting = 0;
    if (ajaxmethod == "POST") {
        ajaxrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxrequest.open(ajaxmethod, url, true);
        ajaxrequest.send({data:prm} );

    }
    ajaxrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //check if request complete
        if (ajaxrequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxrequest.status == 200) {
            var ajaxresponse = ajaxrequest.responseText;
            //enable button
            if (btn != '') { document.getElementById(btn).disabled = false; }
            //if response is to reload page (check if any message is to be displayed);
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 6) == 'RELOAD') { window.location.reload(); return; }
            //if response is to redierct page
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 8) == 'REDIRECT') { var desturl = ajaxresponse.substr(9, 100); window.location = desturl; return; }
            //end wait in wid
            if (document.getElementById(wid) != null) { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = ''; }
            //end wait in rid
            if (document.getElementById(rid) != null) { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ''; }
            //if error or message is to be displayed, it would contain 'ER;'
            if (ajaxresponse.substr(0, 2) == "ER") {
                if (document.getElementById(wid) != null) { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = ajaxresponse.substr(3, (ajaxresponse.length - 1)); };
            }
            else {
                //write output (if not preceded by 'ER;')
                if (document.getElementById(rid) != null) { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ajaxresponse; }
            }
            //if success function is defined, run it
            if (fsuccess != '') { setTimeout(fsuccess, 100); }
            ajaxfinish = 0;
            ajaxwaiting = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (ajaxrequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxrequest.status != 200) {
            //enable button
            if (btn != '') { document.getElementById(btn).disabled = false; }
            //write error in wait
            if (wid != '') { document.getElementById(wid).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/error.gif' width='20' height='20' class='imginline' alt='Error' />An error has occurred. Please try again."; }
            //nullify result container
            if (rid != '') { document.getElementById(rid).innerHTML = ""; }
            //if error function is defined, run it
            if (ferror != '') { setTimeout(ferror, 100); }
            ajaxfinish = 0;
            ajaxwaiting = 0;
            //log it
            //---
        }
    }
    ajaxrequest.send();
    setTimeout("globalajaxabort('" + btn + "','" + wid + "')", 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts @AnantDabhi. My ajax function is actually meant to deal both GET and POST requests. The point where your code resolved my error is using ajaxrequest.send(data) instead of ajaxrequest.send(). I was actually using same method of sending data i.e. adding parameters to the url when opening the request for both GET and POST. Thus, as long as parameter length was within GET limit, the request was working, but as soon as that limit got crossed, it was failing. It was a silly mistake at my end. But thanks a ton to you for saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

In web.config  set `maxAllowedContentLength` .

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
      </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and be sure :

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Just added <security> as suggested under <system.webServer> and still no change. Thanks for super quick response though.